# Problems with Routing URLs using CGI and Bottle.py

Tags: python, .htaccess, cgi, bottle

I've been having difficulty getting anything more than a simple index / to return correctly using bottle.py in a CGI environment.  When I try to return /hello I get a 404 response.  However, if I request /index.py/hello

```
import bottle
from bottle import route

@route('/')
def index():
    return 'Index'

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
    CGIHandler().run(bottle.default_app())
```

And here is my .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.py
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c="">
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.py/$1  [L]
</ifmodule>
```

I copied much of the code from here as I'm using DH and it seemed relevant: http://blog.coderonfire.com/2010/02/running-bottle-python-micro-framework.html

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `<ifmodule>` block is not relevant to your Apache server and the directives to mod_rewrite are not working. Start with the following `.htaccess` and then if you have a need, add the block according to your current apache version.

```
DirectoryIndex index.py
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.py/$1  [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I had to remove the preceeding / on /index.py/$1 but then it works perfectly.

Comment: @enrico, I am not sure I like your edit. I would better remove the leading slash instead of removing the RewriteBase.

Comment: Setting RewriteBase seems excessive when it's just a slash, but certainly makes things easier if that ever changes. However, the real reason I didn't just remove the leading slash is an edit needs to be at least 6 characters, because of the dumb "significant edit" filter. You can put it back and remove the slash if that's your preference.

Comment: @enrico, another problem is that the edit is not relevant to the original question =) I think this is not the only enhancement you can do: for example, I am not sure that in the current configuration the query string is passed to the redirected page (for a long time I have not touched an Apache config).